# What is the difference between acquiring and applying in the visual studio installation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When installing visual studio , 2 bars are shown parallely . One says applying and the other says acquiring . What is the difference between both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're running is the so-called Web Installer. It's just a small bootstrapper that does two things in parallel - the first is download (=acquire) the required packages from Microsoft's servers, and the other is install (=apply) those packages on the local machine.

The installer rightfully knows that the download process needs network I/O while the installation needs disk I/O, and these can be done in parallel rather than downloading a huge multi-GB package and only installing it after it's all done.

Comment: Why does applying still require an internet connection

Comment: Good question. Might require configuration information. Might just be an oversight.

Comment: IMO it is epic stupid from M$ to rename two well understood operations.  Yeah you can infer what it means, but why would you elect not to use the accepted terminology?